# How to put 3 texts in a row so that everything is visible

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm implementing a screen in Jetpack Compose.
The thing I want to achieve is one row with three Text components next to each other so they fit the whole Row.
First is a label, last is counter and in middle, there is the text that can have different lengths. I would like to always show label and counter, and between them the text, if there is no enough space i would like to wrap it to another line.

Something like on the image below:
[image: what i want to achive]

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screeshot]

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun RowExample() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Label",
            color = Red,
            style = typography.h5,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        )
        Text(
            text = "If text is too long, wrap it",
            style = typography.h5,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(8.dp),
        )
        Text(
            text = "(2)",
            color = Green,
            style = typography.h5,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: In the given example "(2)" text is always at the right side of screen. What if i want it be always next to the text and if text takes more space then at the end of the screen?